# Set value textarea RTE

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to set a value for RTE field, but it won't take the value. this line:  **Ae2.val(Ae1); // even this will not work: Ae2.val("Test");** any ideas. thank you

```
function PreSaveAction()
{
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var  Ae2 = $("#ctl00_m_g_1b07d546_aec6_4582_b36d_9bfe97fc36e0_ff26_1_ctl00_ctl00_TextField_inplacerte");
        //SharePoint's Rich text editor
        alert("Ae2 before set val: \n" + Ae2.html());
        Ae2.val(Ae1); // even this will not work: Ae2.val("Test");
        alert("Ae2 after set val: " + Ae2.html());
    });
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Did you try `Ae2.html(Ae1)` ? How does the source of the editor look like?

Comment: Is it plain text rte field or rich text?

Comment: the field is enhanced rich text.

Answer (score 0):

Please try as follows

```
$('iframe[id^="ctl00_m_g_1b07d546_aec6_4582_b36d_9bfe97fc36e0_ff26_1_ctl00_ctl00_TextField_inplacerte"]').contents().find("body").html("Test");
```